# Derby foreign key

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

Hello guys and good day.
I have Table "T1" that has primary key "ID" and another Table "T2" that has foreign key "T1ID" reference from the primary key"ID", My problem is the foreign key does not show any records that I insert from the primary key "ID", it should shows the data of the records what I insert in the primary key.

[image]

and this is the code that I execute to make foreign key:

```
Alter table T2 add FOREIGN KEY (T1ID) references T1(ID);
```

Please help and thank you in advance.

Foreign key"T1ID" supposed to shows the data of the records what I insert in the primary key"ID"

Comment: Those tables don't look real. What are the actual columns and how to want the tables to relate?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand [what a foreign key is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) and what it does. A foreign key doesn't "show any records" or "show the data". You use SQL `SELECT` statements to show records and show data.

A foreign key is an integrity constraint, and it instructs the database engine to enforce certain integrity rules. A foreign key tells the database that it should enforce a relationship between two table. In this case, specifically, you are telling the database to enforce the validity of the values in the `t2.t1id` column.

So the database will ensure that for each row in `t2`, the value in `t2.t1id` from that row is a value of `t1.id` for some row in `t1`.

The database will then do things like:

- refuse to let you insert a row in `t2` with a value of `t2.t1id` that doesn't exist in any row in `t1`
- and refuse to let you delete a row from `t1` if there are any rows in `t2` which have values of `t1id` that match that particular `t1.id` value.